# What's wrong with my code in python?

Tags: python

This is my 2nd day studying python at home. I just wondering if i can put the def function inside the if statement. 
Example :

```
def result(variable_1, variable_2):
    return variable_1 + variable_2

print(result(20,20))
```

now our result will be 40 because of the code variable_1 + variable_2
then when i put it on the if statement

```
if result == 40:
    print ("we made it")
else:
    print ("Nooope")
```

the result that i always get is this :

```
40
"Nooope"
```

and i just want to know why? it should be "we made it" right coz my result is 40 and it is equal to 40.

Comment: Fix your indentation, please. And clarify comments below.

Comment: It isn't easy to understand what you want? What do you mean put def in if? Do you want `i*def*f`? That can also be explained as putting def in if. Please clarify your question.

Comment: You can put a function definition inside an if statement body, but I am puzzled as why would want to (in this context).  Are you trying to say `result(20, 20) == 4`?  That's also valid.

Comment: okay sorry for that, i edit it, i wish you could understand it by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(result(20,20))
```

this only prints the result of 20+20 and does not save the result of the op into "result", "result" is the name of the function. if you want to save the return value,

```
answer = result(20,20)
print answer
if answer == 40:
    print ("we made it")
else:
    print ("Nooope")
```

take note that `print result` would result in:

```
<function result at 0x4095ed8>
```

that is actually the funciton object.

hope it helps to clarify a little.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH ! IT IS SO VERY HELPFUL MEN ! GOD BLESS !

Comment: i figured it out <3 ^_^